# Bootstrap3 Modal resizing but not image

Tags: resize

OK this one has got me....

In normal browser image within modal is no problem
Change platform (table or phone) and the modal resizes correctly but the image does not..

The thing that driving me made is I using the same code and bootstrap.css I used on the last project and that works perfectly .... nothing has change in the code or the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use class `img-responsive` . Like `<img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />` . If problem not solve then show your code to understand.

Comment: If your problem has solved then please don't forget to accept answer @user3767402